# IntelliJ + MacBook Touch Bar - How to put a "complex" shortcut into the Touch Bar please?

Tags: intellij-idea

Small question regarding IntelliJ and the MacBook Touch Bar.

It is well known via Settings -> Preferences -> Menus and Toolbars -> Touch Bar -> Default -> "+" sign -> Add Action, one can add onto the MacBook Touch Bar whatever is available within the offered choices.

How about cases where it is not in the drop down?
For instance, I am binding more "complex" shortcuts sometime up to 4 buttons (Shift+Control+Command+Letter) to an action.

Hence, I would like to specify to the Touch Bar, "add me an icon/button which replaces having to press four keys at the same time".

Question, How to create a MacBook Touch Bar icon/button that I can configure being the equivalent of (Shift+Control+Command+ CONFIGURABLE Letter) please?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Default with ... key** group in **Touch Bar** actions to add the actions there when you press corresponding modifier key:

[image]

See also a related request: [IDEA-219425](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219425) Add more modifier options to the Touch Bar Debugger mode.